# Solr DataImportHandler 1 to many relation

Tags: solr

I have setup MySQL tables for storing articles.
Basically, they look like this:

```
article
-------
article_number
title

sets_article
-------
setcode
article_number
```

I have setup a schema.xml and configured the DataImportHandler. Everything works fine except, that the sets are not stored, when I call the DataImportHandler with full-import.

Here is my the relevant part of my data-config.xml:

```
<document name="articles">
    <entity name="article" 
            pk="article_number"
            query="select * from article" 

            deltaImportQuery="select * from article where article_number='${dih.delta.article_number}'"
            deltaQuery="select article_number from article where tstamp &gt; UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('${dih.last_index_time}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))">

            <entity name="sets_article" query="select setcode as sets from sets_article where article_number='${article.article_number}'" />
            <entity name="sets_articlel2" query="select distinct setcode as sets2 from sets_article" />
            <entity name="sets_articlel3" query="select distinct setcode as sets3 from sets_article where article_number='11112222'" />

    </entity>
</document>
```

The entities sets_article2 and sets_article3 work fine, so I think there is a problem with:

```
where article_number='${article.article_number}'
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with this setup?

Comment: Try to write the `article_number` of `where article_number='${article.article_number}'` all uppercase. Like `article_number='${article.ARTICLE_NUMBER}'`

Comment: @cheffe: Unfortunately, this has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple misconfiguration.
The tables didn't have the proper primary keys set.